# Mating board members with gangsters algorithm

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a list of board members of all companies in the city. In the city lives three gangsters. Every company needs to have at least two gangsters among the friends of board members but every board member can know at most one gangster. Member can be a board member in multiple companies.

What is the name of this problem? What topic should I explore to solve it?

Comment: There are far more possible problems one could set than "names".  That's the great thing about the English language -- is that it lets us describe problems that we haven't encountered before.  So, asking for the "name" of a problem is rarely useful, because most problems you run across won't have a "name".

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. You have listed some requirements, but it's not clear what you want an algorithm to do.  What do you want the output from the algorithm to be?  Do you want to check whether all of the companies have met these requirements?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this problem?  Can you credit the original source for the problem in your question, or explain the motivation or how you ran across it?

Comment: Also, "mating" means either "checkmating at chess" or "having sex for purely reproductive reasons, as animals do." I doubt you mean either of these things. Perhaps "matching"?

Comment: Do you want to find such a allocation? Show it always (or sometimes, or never) exists? See only if it is possible or not for a specific case?